# How to remove a node using Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div>
  This is
  <p> very
    <script>
      some code
    </script>
  </p>
   important.
</div>
```

I know how to get a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` from this:

```
dom.xpath("//div")
```

I now want to filter out any `script` tag:

```
dom.xpath("//script")
```

So I can get something like:

```
<div>
  This is
  <p> very</p>
   important.
</div>
```

So that I can call `div.text` to get:

```
"This is very important."
```

I tried recursively/iteratively going over all children nodes and trying to match every node I want to filter out any node I don't want, but I ran into problems like too much whitespace or not enough whitespace. I'm quite sure there's a nice enough and rubyesque way.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, along with "[mcve]". We need to see the minimum code you wrote that demonstrates the problem. Without that it looks like you haven't tried. If you're familiar with a NodeSet, then you should have seen [`unlink` AKA `remove`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#remove-instance_method) in the NodeSet documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1st problem

To remove all the script nodes :

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = "<div>
  This is
  <p> very
    <script>
      some code
    </script>
  </p>
   important.
</div>"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.xpath("//script").remove

p doc.text
#=> "\n  This is\n   very\n    \n  \n   important.\n"
```

Thanks to @theTinMan for his tip (calling `remove` on one NodeSet instead of each Node).

## 2nd problem

To remove the unneeded whitespaces, you can use :

- `strip` to remove spaces (whitespace, tabs, newlines, ...) at beginning and end of string
- `gsub` to replace mutiple spaces by just one whitespace

```
p doc.text.strip.gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,' ')
#=> "This is very important."
```

Comment: You can use `remove` on the resulting NodeSet without iterating over it with `each` and the block. http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#remove-instance_method

Answer (score 2):

NodeSet contains the [`remove`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#remove-instance_method) method which makes it easy to remove whatever matched your selector:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('p').remove
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <body>
# >>     <div></div>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

Applied to your sample input:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div>
  This is
  <p> very
    <script>
      some code
    </script>
  </p>
  important.
</div>
EOT

doc.search('script').remove
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <div>
# >>   This is
# >>   <p> very
# >>     
# >>   </p>
# >>    important.
# >> </div>
# >> </body></html>
```

At that point the text in the `<div>` is:

```
doc.at('div').text # => "\n  This is\n   very\n    \n  \n   important.\n"
```

Normalizing that is easy:

```
doc.at('div').text.gsub(/[\n ]+/,' ').strip # => "This is very important."
```